# apply different styles based on window width, jquery

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I am trying to check the viewport size, and then apply different styles based on whether the viewport size is between 768px - 992px, using an if and else statement. However, what I've got so far isn't working.

Here is my code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    function checkwindowSize() {
        if(windowSize > 768 && windowSize < 992) {
            $('#show-menu').css('visibility', 'hidden', function() {
                $('#slide-menu-container').css('visibility', 'visible');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#show-menu').css('visibility', 'visible', function() {
                $('#slide-menu-container').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a job for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of using media queries! Just out of interest though, is there anything you can see that is wrong with my code? Thank you!

Comment: If i use show, can i do this...

Comment: if(windowSize > 768 && windowSize < 992) {
   $('#show-menu').show(, function() {

Comment: because i want to run another event as well as this one in the if statement!

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/kxvt8/2/

Answer (score 2):

Why not use css?? Like:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) { 
    #showmenu{

    }
 }

 @media (min-width: 993px) { 
    #showmenu{

    }
 }
  @media (max-width: 767px) { 
    #showmenu{

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Define your windowSize variable inside the checkwindowSize function.

@media query is preferred then javascript.

```
function checkwindowSize() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    if(windowSize > 768 && windowSize < 992) {
        $('#show-menu').css('visibility', 'hidden', function() {
            $('#slide-menu-container').css('visibility', 'visible');
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#show-menu').css('visibility', 'visible', function() {
            $('#slide-menu-container').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        });
    }
}   

checkwindowSize();

$(window).resize(function(){checkwindowSize()});
```

[**Fiddle Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/H2hwQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Has Frédéric Hamidi said, CSS media query are the best way to do it.

To answer your question, in your code sample you never call the checkwindowSize() function.
Also to improve your code you can call you function every time the browser is resized using the
"resize" event. http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the if you still want to use Jquery for this purpose [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/B8Pkw/)

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

     if($( window ).width() <= 500)
     {
         $( ".smallerSize" ).css('display','block');
     }
     else
     {
        $( ".biggerSize" ).css('display','block');
     }
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
     if ($( window ).width() <= 500)
     {
         $( ".biggerSize" ).css('display','none');
         $( ".smallerSize" ).css('display','block');
     }
     else
     {
         $( ".smallerSize" ).css('display','none');
         $( ".biggerSize" ).css('display','block');
     }

});
```

**CSS**

```
.smallerSize
{
    display:none;
}

.biggerSize
{
    display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="smallerSize">
    <span>Small Size</span>
</div>

<div class="biggerSize">
    <span>Bigger Size</span>
</div>
```

Here you have 2 conditions, 1st one is when the page is loaded and 2nd condition is when the browser size is changing.You can see the demo for this approach